# How to add the jQuery date picker in Angularjs ui-grid?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-datepicker, ui-grid, celltemplate

I have been trying to add `Jquery Datepicker` in `Angularjs`  UI-grid by using with custom cell template.

When I select a `date` from the `Jquery date picker`, `UI-Grid` functionalities are not working for that respective cell once the `JQuery date picker` finished loading.

I tried forcefully removing the DOM element in custom directory, though no luck.

```
$scope.editableCellTemplateFrom = '<div ui-grid-editor><form name="inputForm" ><input type="text"  readonly  data-ng-model="row.entity.validFrom" extdatepicker /></form></div>' ;


customdirectives.directive('extdatepicker', function (uiGridConstants,$timeout) {
    return{
    restrict: 'A',          
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, Ctrl) {

    element.datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy', 
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true,
    onSelect: function(d,i){
    $timeout(function(){
    scope.row.isDirty = true;
    scope.row.entity.validFrom = d;
    element.parent().parent().removeAttr("aria-selected");
    element.parent().parent().find('div').removeClass("ui-grid-cell-contents-hidden ui-grid-cell-focus");
    element.parent().remove();
    //scope.row.grid.api.rowEdit.setRowsDirty([scope.row.entity]);
    if (!scope.row.grid.api.rowEdit.dirtyRows ){
    scope.row.grid.api.rowEdit.dirtyRows = [];
    }
    scope.row.grid.api.rowEdit.dirtyRows.push(scope.row.entity);
    //scope.row.grid.api.edit.raise.afterCellEdit(scope.row.entity, scope.col.colDef);
    scope.row.grid.api.edit.raise.cancelCellEdit(scope.row.entity, scope.col.colDef);

    //scope.row.grid.api.edit.raise.cancelCellEdit(scope.row.entity, scope.col.colDef);
    //scope.row.grid.api.core.notifyDataChange(uiGridConstants.dataChange.EDIT);

    //scope.row.grid.api.core.notifyDataChange( uiGridConstants.dataChange.COLUMN );
    scope.row.grid.api.core.raise.columnVisibilityChanged( scope.col);

    scope.$apply();

    scope.row.grid.api.core.refresh();
    //endEdit
    },1000);
    }
    });  

    }            
    }
    });
```

How to enable/refresh `ui-grid` functionalities once the `JQuery date pciker` has loaded its value in `cell-grid`.

versions used are angular `v1.2.3`, `ui-grid v3.0.6`.

Comment: did u try with https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#datepicker ?

Comment: Entire application has uses jquery date picker. So i supposed to use the same.